# Пунктуация в вопросе "И что вы думаете это значит?"

Tags: пунктуация

В интернете нашла несколько вариантов пунктуации в этом вопросе: с одной запятой, двумя, так и вовсе без них.

*И что, вы думаете, это значит?*

*И что вы думаете, это значит?*

*И что вы думаете это значит?*

Как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правилен вариант с двумя запятыми.

> **Что**, вы думаете, **это значит**?

Здесь в вопрос "**Что это значит?**" вставлено *вводное предложение* (Валгина, Розенталь, Фомина, Современный русский язык http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-174.htm ) "**вы думаете**". Такие предложения выполняют ту же функцию, что вводные слова и могут присоединяться бессоюзным способом. На тех же основаниях такие предложения *обособляются* запятыми:

> *A вы, я вижy, шeлкoвый* (Typгeнeв).
>   http://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/vvodnie-predlozheniya/?q=486&n=397

В нашем случае без изменения смысла можно заменить вводное предложение словом "*по-вашему*"  (такие слова обособляются на основании *указания на источник сообщения*):

> **Что**, по вашему, **это значит**?

-- или переформулировать вопрос так:

> *Как* вы думаете, **что это значит**?

Answer (score 4):

Интересный вопрос! По запросу именно этого предложения не удалось ничего найти. Захотелось порассуждать. С удовольствием почитаю критику и другие ответы.

В данном предложении-вопросе явно видны две грамматические основы: ***вы видите*** и ***это значит***. Понятно, что весь смысл заключается в простом предложении ***И что это значит?***, в середину которого вклинивается что-то наподобие вводного (типа *как вы знаете*, *думается*, *скажем*). Соответственно, подходит вариант с двумя запятыми (может, и с большой натяжкой, потому что не будет выглядеть так же органично, как, например, ***И что, скажите на милость, это значит?***).

С другой стороны, всё это выражение читается легко, без пауз, на одном дыхании, и совсем не хочется ставить каких-либо знаков. ***Вы думаете*** воспринимается как частица, не несущая обращения к кому-либо конкретному и не требующая ответа именно от него (них). Вопрос будет нести оттенок риторического.

На [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE) попалось вот что:

> Запятые не нужны. В подобных вопросительно-восклицательных предложениях слова *видишь, знаешь* не выделяются запятыми. Ср.: *Потом лето было знаешь какое! Там знаешь какое положение? Нас знаешь сколько болельщиков! Я нашёл в углу знаете что? А он видишь что делает?*

По крайней мере, на данный момент для меня точно не приемлем вариант с одной запятой: *И что вы думаете, это значит?* Он не поддерживает ни смысл, ни грамматику. Его можно только разделить на две части: *И что вы думаете? Что это значит?*

Больше склоняюсь к варианту без запятых, особенно если убрать местоимение ***вы***: *И что думаете это значит?*

Answer (score 2):

1. Я очень часто говорю на форуме о том, **как важен контекст.** Мы же чаще рассматриваем отдельное предложение, оторванное от своей естественной среды. (А иногда нам даже присылают только фрагмент предложения.)
2. Вот и в данном случае происходит именно так.

*Что, **вы думаете**, это значит?*

Это принятый ответ, и он наиболее вероятный и частотный. То есть это **реальный вопрос,** обращенный к собеседнику, в котором обособлено вводное предложение.

3. **Возможны ли другие варианты?** В принципе, да. Но для этого реальный вопрос нужно превратить **в риторический** и подобрать соответствующий текст, например:

*Только никаких сокровищ там не оказалось. И что **думаете** это значит? Их там и не было никогда!*

Подобный  вариант (с частицей, а с не вводным словом) предлагал нам Александр Стрелец. Немного похоже на предложение из его ответа: **Я нашёл в углу знаете что?**

4. **Таким образом,** разное оформление одного и того же предложения надо всегда соотносить с контекстом.